# Get database if combobox is selected in data table

Tags: javascript, xpages

I've created a functionality where I can get all the databases that are listed my view. After that I loop through all the documents and can display them accordingly in data table using computedFields.

Here's the code that I have:

```
try
{
var viewDocs:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();

var relcol = database.search("Form='dbPick_Kappa'");

var bazu_skaits= relcol.getCount();
var doc:NotesDocument = relcol.getFirstDocument();
var alldocs:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();

for (j=1;j<bazu_skaits+1;j++)
{
    viewDocs.add(doc);

    var serveris = doc.getItemValueString("Server_P");
    var datubaze = doc.getItemValueString("Filename_P");

    var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(serveris, datubaze,false);
    var sender = getComponent("senderBox").getValue();
    var allrelevant:NotesDocumentCollection = db.search("StatusFlag='" + sender + "'");
    var skaits = allrelevant.getCount();
    var tmpDoc = allrelevant.getFirstDocument();

    for (i=1;i<skaits+1;i++)
    {
        alldocs.add(tmpDoc);
        tmpDoc = allrelevant.getNextDocument(tmpDoc);
    }

    doc = relcol.getNextDocument(doc);
}
return alldocs;

}
catch(e)
{
    kk = e.toString();
}
```

The code works ok if I want to select all databases that I have in my view. What I'm wondering about is there a way to select the databases that I need with including a checkbox in my data table? So by doig this I could check the checkbox and if it's checked it would return the database that has checkbox selected near it. Hopefully someone will understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Data iterators like View Panel, Data View etc will have a getSelectedIds() method that will allow you to get the NoteIDs of the selected elements for the current page of the view. I'm not sure if that's in a DataTable, but if you're displaying view entries a DataTable offers little benefit over a View Panel. The View Panel also allows you to add components into a column, you just have to copy and paste the XML for the component into the relevant location on the source pane - the drop action moves any components outside the View Panel.

Also, you should get into the habit of always recycling in loops (unless you're using the OpenNTF Domino API, which does it for you). Not doing so could crash the server if enough Domino objects are accessed during the request (page load / partial refresh). See this blog post http://www.intec.co.uk/the-perils-of-getcolumnvalues-get0/